# macOS Applications built in .NET Framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have an assignment that is requiring that I build and deploy an application that can be run on windows and mac, I was going to create two production branches and two debugging branches for each platform, My strongest language is vb.net, but the main issue I can't solve is that I need to deploy to macOS, My question is how can I best achieve this. any suggestions or feedback will help greatly.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [What is .NET Framework?](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet-framework), [What is .NET?](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet) and [What is .NET MAUI?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui)

Comment: this requires me to know c# correct? My comfort zone is vb.net

Comment: *"My comfort zone is vb.net"*. So expand your comfort zone. It's mainly just different syntax. The principles are all the same.